# Prove that $\frac{1}{\left|1-\frac{|x|}{|y|}\right|}\leq \frac{1}{\left|1-\frac{\delta_x}{\delta_y}\right|}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $|x|\leq \delta_x$ and $|y|\geq \delta_y$ where $\delta_x, \delta_y >0$ and $\delta_x< \delta_y $. Prove that
$$\frac{1}{\left|1-\frac{|x|}{|y|}\right|}\leq \frac{1}{\left|1-\frac{\delta_x}{\delta_y}\right|}$$
Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{|x|}{|y|}\leq \frac{\delta_x}{\delta_y},
$$
so
$$
1-\frac{\delta_x}{\delta_y} \leq 1 - \frac{|x|}{|y|}.
$$
Now $\frac{\delta_x}{\delta_y} <1$ since $\delta_y > \delta_x$ then we can write
$$
\left|1-\frac{\delta_x}{\delta_y}\right| \leq \left|1 - \frac{|x|}{|y|}\right|,
$$
from which we can see
$$
\frac{1}{\left|1 - \frac{|x|}{|y|}\right|} \leq \frac{1}{\left|1-\frac{\delta_x}{\delta_y}\right|}.
$$